# In smartctl, what does means "Percentage used endurance indicator too short"?

Tags: smart, bacula, smartctl

I use Bacula to make backups.  When i use `smartctl`

```
# smartctl -H -l error /dev/st0
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

TapeAlert: OK
Percentage used endurance indicator too short (pl=6)

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
           ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0        0         0         0          0          0.000           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0          0.000           0
```

What does actually means the message `Percentage used endurance indicator too short` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug fixed 6 months ago, more on https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/314.